# TYPO3 generate link menu of subpage/level 2

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript

If I have this code I can generate a link menu. and say that I only want to include Uid 4 and 8.

```
lib.leftNavi = HMENU
lib.leftNavi.entryLevel=0
lib.leftNavi.special = list
lib.leftNavi.special.value = 4,8
lib.leftNavi.1 = TMENU
lib.leftNavi.1 {
  wrap = <div id="leftMenu"><ul class="L1">|</ul></div>
  expAll = 0
  NO = 1
  NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
  NO.stdWrap.wrap = <span>|</span>
  RO < .NO
  RO = 1
  CUR < .NO
  CUR = 1
  CUR.allWrap = <li class="current">|</li>
  CUR.stdWrap.wrap = <span>|</span>
  CUR.ATagParams =  
  ACT < .CUR
}
```

My question is now..

How can I say that I want to generate a link menu, from/of the sub pages under Uid 4, so it don't show the link to Uid 4, but the 3-5 sub-pages under this Uid ?

..UPDATE..

Okay I have this code now, and its almost OK.

```
lib.prodNavi = HMENU
lib.prodNavi.entryLevel=0
lib.prodNavi.special = list
lib.prodNavi.special.value = 5
lib.prodNavi.1 = TMENU
lib.prodNavi.1 {
    wrap = <div id="categorylist-box"><div id="categorylist-box-top"><h2><em>Produkter</em></h2></div><div id="categorylist-box-content"><ul>|</ul></div><div id="categorylist-box-bottom"></div></div><div class="pagecontent-box" id="pagecontent-box-59">
    expAll = 1
    NO = 1
    NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
    NO.stdWrap.wrap = <span>|</span>
    NO.doNotShowLink = 0
    NO.doNotShowLink.stdWrap.override = 1
    NO.doNotShowLink.stdWrap.if {
        equals.field = uid
        value = 5
    }
    RO < .NO
    RO = 1
    CUR < .NO
    CUR = 1
    CUR.allWrap = <li class="current">|</li>
    CUR.stdWrap.wrap = <span>|</span>
    CUR.ATagParams =
    ACT < .CUR
}
lib.prodNavi.2 < lib.prodNavi.1
```

But it show me to oranges boxes, almost as it using the Wrap 2 times.
[image: 2 times wrapper]

How do I only show it like this, with one wrap.

[image: one wrapper]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use doNotShowLink = 1 for hiding menu items. And you can use stdWrap.override for hiding single items.

Here you would show uid 8 and subpages and subpages of uid 4. uid 4 itself would not be shown

```
lib.leftNavi = HMENU
lib.leftNavi.entryLevel=0
lib.leftNavi.special = list
lib.leftNavi.special.value = 4,8
lib.leftNavi.1 = TMENU
lib.leftNavi.1 {
    wrap = <div id="leftMenu"><ul class="L1">|</ul></div>
    expAll = 1
    NO = 1
    NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
    NO.stdWrap.wrap = <span>|</span>
    NO.doNotShowLink = 0
    NO.doNotShowLink.stdWrap.override = 1
    NO.doNotShowLink.stdWrap.if {
        equals.field = uid
        value = 4
    }
    RO < .NO
    RO = 1
    CUR < .NO
    CUR = 1
    CUR.allWrap = <li class="current">|</li>
    CUR.stdWrap.wrap = <span>|</span>
    CUR.ATagParams =
    ACT < .CUR
}
lib.leftNavi.2 < lib.leftNavi.1
```

UPDATE:

For Using the wrap only once just use it for the HMENU, not for the TMENU:

```
lib.prodNavi = HMENU
lib.prodNavi.entryLevel=0
lib.prodNavi.special = list
lib.prodNavi.special.value = 252
lib.prodNavi.wrap = <div id="categorylist-box"><div id="categorylist-box-top"><h2><em>Produkter</em></h2></div><div id="categorylist-box-content"><ul>|</ul></div><div id="categorylist-box-bottom"></div></div><div class="pagecontent-box" id="pagecontent-box-59">
lib.prodNavi.1 = TMENU
lib.prodNavi.1 {
    expAll = 1
    NO = 1
    NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
    NO.stdWrap.wrap = <span>|</span>
    NO.doNotShowLink = 0
    ...
}
lib.prodNavi.2 < lib.prodNavi.1
```